# How to combine multiple CSV files in PHP

Tags: php, csv

I have many CSV files with the same number of lines, such as the following

```
name   age
Tom     18
John    16
Crisp   22
```

```
countries
The United States
Britain
Japan
```

```
professional
engineer
accountant
painter
```

Now I want to combine them into a separate CSV that looks something like this

```
name   age    country            professional
Tom     18    The United States  engineer
John    16    Britain            accountant
Crisp   22    Japan              painter
```

Maybe I have more CSV files, and I need to synthesize them into a CSV file
What should I do? Read each line of the CSV file and then write it back?
Any help please

Comment: Read each line from each file. Do array_merge() of them and write a new line in the new csv file.

Comment: CSV files are just some comma delimited files, so just append other rows with ',' and save them as CSV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It the files are not too big, the easiest solution is to store all the data into a global array and output it when all the data are read :

```
$delimiter = "\t" ;
$input_files = array('users.csv', 'countries.csv', 'professions.csv'); // files to merge

// read all the data, store them in $result
$result = array(); // final array with merged fields
foreach($input_files as $file)
{
    $reader = fopen($file, 'r');
    
    $line_index = 0 ;
    while($line = fgetcsv($reader, null, $delimiter) )
    {
        if(! array_key_exists($line_index, $result)) // if the line doesn't exist in the result yet, create it
            $result[$line_index] = array();
        
        $result[$line_index] = array_merge($result[$line_index], $line) ; // append the current field to the existing line
        ++$line_index;
    }    
    fclose($reader);
}

// output the result
$writer = fopen('result.csv', 'w+');
foreach($result as $row)
{
    fputcsv($writer, $row, $delimiter);
}
fclose($writer);
```

Output :

```
name    age countries   professional
Tom 18  "The United States" engineer
John    16  Britain accountant
Crisp   22  Japan   painter
```